# Why is my KnockoutJS custom binding being triggered?

Tags: javascript, data-binding, binding, mvvm, knockout.js

I've got an odd situation. Basically, I have two custom bindings which are used to animate the DOM element to it's new value. These are aWidth and aRight, which animate the width and right values respectively.

I've implemented the bindings like this:

```
<div class='classname' data-bind="aRight: right, aWidth: containerWidth, style: { zIndex: zindex, left: (left() + 'px'), height: (containerHeight() + 'px') }">
```

... and the custom bindings look like this:

```
            ko.bindingHandlers.aWidth =
            {
                update: function (element, valueAccessor, allBindingsAccessor, context)
                {
                    // Get the value accessor
                    var value = valueAccessor();

                    // Get the new width and the duration of the animation
                    var newWidth = ko.utils.unwrapObservable(value);
                    var duration = 500;

                    $(element).animate({ width: newWidth }, duration, "swing");
                }
            };

            ko.bindingHandlers.aRight =
            {
                update: function (element, valueAccessor, allBindingsAccessor, context)
                {
                    // Get the value accessor
                    var value = valueAccessor();

                    // Get the new width and the duration of the animation
                    var newRight = ko.utils.unwrapObservable(value);
                    var duration = 500;

                    $(element).animate({ right: newRight }, duration, "swing");

                    console.log("aRight Called: newRight - " + newRight + ", duration - " + duration);
                }
            };
```

So the problem comes around when we change an observable other than my two custom bound observables, for instance zindex.

If we change the observable zindex, the value gets updated correctly in the DOM, but for some reason, my aRight binding also gets triggered!...

I don't have any reference to it in my aRight custom binding so there surely can't be a dependency?

My aRight binding also gets triggered when my aWidth binding is triggered too, which is also a little odd!

Does anyone have any ideas about this?

Thanks a lot!

Andy.

**Update**

This is the part of the view model which updates the index, which when causes my aRight custom binding to fire (this is very much psudo-code by the way!):

```
    var page = function()
    {
        this.zindex = ko.observable(0);
        this.right = ko.observable(0);
        // and other observables....
    }

    var viewModel = function()
    {
        var pages = ko.oberservableArray();
        // populate the pages array etc...

        this.someMethod = function()
        {
            // Do some stuff...
            this.anotherMethod();
            // Do some other stuff
        }
        .bind(this);

        this.anotherMethod() = function
        {
            var pageCount = this.pages().length;
            for (var pageNum = 0; pageNum < pageCount; pageNum++)
            {
                var page = this.pages()[pageNum];
                page.zindex(/* a different value */); // This is what causes my aRight binding to fire...
            }
        }
        .bind(this);
    }
```

**Update**

I just read a post here: http://groups.google.com/group/knockoutjs/browse_thread/thread/26a3157ae68c7aa5/44c96d1b748f63bb?lnk=gst&q=custom+binding+firing#44c96d1b748f63bb

Saying:

> Additionally, a binding will have its update function run again, if
>   another  binding in the same data-bind attribute is triggered as well.

Does this mean that what I am seeing is that my custom binding is being triggered when any other binding the in data-bind attribute is triggered (it just so happens maybe that zindex is the first that I see change)? Is this not a bit odd/wrong?...

**Update**

I've got a simple fiddle which I think pretty much sums up my problem. It seems like any binding on the same data-bind attribute as much custom binding will cause it to update!

http://jsfiddle.net/J6EPx/2/

Hmmm... guess I'll have to work around it by manually checking in my custom binding as to whether the value has actually changed or not!! Does this not defeat that actual point of a binding???

I've also posted a more precise question on the Knockout forums: http://groups.google.com/group/knockoutjs/browse_thread/thread/d2290d96e33f1d5a

Comment: I wonder if it's something to do with $(element).animate()? What happens if instead of animating you just change the width / height directly?

Comment: Good question... give me a sec... :)

Comment: @Alex Key, nah, using $(element).css("right", newRight + "px"); didn't help at least. Still being triggered when index is updated! Thanks for the suggestion though!

Comment: Intruiging, that's an odd one! This question has got a star from me :-) I'm interested in seeing what your solution is, good luck. I'm playing with knockout myself, so if I figure it out I'll drop you a line.

Comment: Thanks, I'll keep this post updated! :)

Comment: can you share your view model?

Comment: @nEEbz it's a wee bit tricky to show all of it unfortunately, but I'll update my question with what I can!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This is currently by design.  All bindings in a data-bind are triggered when any of bindings fire.  This is because they are all wrapped in a single dependentObservable.  In some cases, bindings have a dependency between each other (if options are updated, then value needs to run to ensure that it is still a valid value).  However, in some cases, this does cause a problem.

There is a different pattern that you can use when creating a custom binding that helps to mitigate this behavior.  Instead of defining the guts of your functionality in the "update" function, you would actually create your own dependentObservable in the "init" function.  It would look like:

```
ko.bindingHandlers.custBinding= {
    init: function(element, valueAccessor) {
        ko.dependentObservable({
            read: function() {
                ko.utils.unwrapObservable(valueAccessor());
                alert("custBinding triggered"); 
            },
            disposeWhenNodeIsRemoved: element
        });
    }
};
```

http://jsfiddle.net/rniemeyer/uKUfy/

Comment: Took a little while to get my head around that, but your suggestion sounds sensible! I must admit though, I'm a little surprised that the default is to wrap them all in a single dependentObservable. I don't think WPF / Silverlight work this way... not to say it's wrong... just confusing! :)

Comment: The default behavior is not ideal in many cases and could/should be improved.  We will just have to balance that with breaking the existing behavior (some people currently use custom bindings that don't access observables and rely on other bindings being triggered).